# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException (jtable)

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Having problem populating the JTable with contents from MySQL.
First, it works when I output the contents of the table on console (system.out). 
The Error: NullPointerException happens when I try display it on JTable.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class ProductTable extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public ProductTable() {

     try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory_db","root","");

     }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
     }    
     try{
       String query = "SELECT * FROM items_in_hand";
       st = con.prepareStatement(query);
       rs = st.executeQuery(query);
       System.out.println("Records from Inventory Database:");
       itemTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); //this line here causes the error
       while(rs.next()){

            String iname = rs.getString("ItemName");
            String price = rs.getString("Price");
            String qty = rs.getString("Quantity");
            System.out.println("Item: "+ iname +"  Price (each): "+price+"  Quantity: "+qty);
       }       
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println("Error: "+ ex);
    }    
    initComponents();     // i have long initComponent codes;
}


private void btn_addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    message.setText("");  
    message2.setText("");
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) itemTable.getModel();
    if(!txt_item.getText().trim().equals("")){
        try{
            String sql = "INSERT INTO items_in_hand (ItemName, Price, Quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setString(1,txt_item.getText());         
            st.setString(2,txt_price.getText());  
            st.setString(3,txt_quantity.getText());
            st.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , "Saved.");
            model.addRow(new Object[] {txt_item.getText(),txt_price.getText(),txt_quantity.getText()});
            message2.setText("Successfully Added.");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null , ex);
        }  
    }
    else{
        message.setText("The Item name must be provided.");
    }
}                                                               



public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ProductTable().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private Connection con;
private PreparedStatement st = null;
private ResultSet rs; 
}
```

run:
Records from Inventory Database:
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Can anyone help?

Comment: i tried changing rs = st.executeQuery(query); to rs = st.executeQuery(); still doesnt work.

Comment: Hi, please paste the stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help sooner :)

Comment: Have you initialized `itemTable`?

Comment: The problem is because DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel() is returning a null, you should check this method.

Comment: I updated the codes above. Can you check?

Comment: @vhax i put resultset on it: DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs), could that still return a null?

Comment: Why don't you just check if it *does* return `null`, or if `itemTable` is `null` at that point?

Comment: @DavidConrad itemTable has contents. it displays when i tried to display it on console. how can i check if it returns null?

Comment: Just move `initComponents();` to the very top of the constructor, right before the first `try{`

Comment: How can you check if it returns null? Assign it to a variable, System.out.print, debugger???

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you for that, i'll do it when i'll be troubleshooting return values.

Comment: Do not use select * in queries. Enumerate your columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do  `new ProductTable().setVisible(true);` your constructor is getting called and executed the logic of fetching data from db and

when you do  `itemTable.setModel();` itemTable is null because you didn't initialize it which I believe you are doing in `initComponents();`  method which gets called later

Comment: ahh got it. the initComponents() must be called before setModel() so the table is will be initialized. thanks I appreciate your help!